# Startup Parameters greyed out in SSCM for new instance

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2016, startup, windows-server, configuration-manager

We do not appear to be able to change the startup parameters for a new SQL Server instance, using SQL Server Configuration Manager (see screenshot below).

[image]

We are members of the sysadmin fixed server role, and are running SSCM version 2015.0130.16111.04 for Microsoft SQL Server 2016 (SP2-CU6) (KB4488536) - 13.0.5292.0 (X64) Enterprise Edition.

Comment: Unfortunately, running SSCM as Administrator does not resolve the issue.

Answer (score 2):

As stated in the comment, please check your privilege. This change you are trying to make will write startup parameters to the registry and need privilege beyond member of sysadmin role in SQL Server.

Ref: [SCM Services - Configure Server Startup Options](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/scm-services-configure-server-startup-options?view=sql-server-2017)

**Limitations and Restrictions**

> SQL Server Configuration Manager writes startup parameters to the
>   registry. They take effect upon the next startup of the Database
>   Engine.
>
> On a cluster, changes must be made on the active server when SQL
>   Server is online, and will take effect when the Database Engine is
>   restarted. The registry update of the startup options on the other
>   node will occur upon the next failover.

**Security**

**Permissions**

Configuring server startup options is restricted to users who can
change the related entries in the registry. This includes the
following users.

- Members of the local administrators group.
- The domain account that is used by SQL Server, if the Database Engine
  is configured to run under a domain account.

Comment: Thank you - we are waiting for the account privileges to be amended, and will confirm if this makes a difference as soon as they have been made.

Comment: **Close SQL Server Configuration Manager** and open SQL Server Configuration Manager in admin mode.